# How long does it take

Tags: statistics

Assume you have a repeating Job,  s single Job takes 1 min execution time and you will succeed with  98 % doing this job correct. 
Your complete Task is to repeat this Job n times, no error is allowed, once you fail you have to start from the beginning.

The Minimum time for sure is  1 min  *  n  times = n minutes. How to consider now the failure Ratio ?

Answer (score 1):

Start with small $n$.  Can you do it for $n=1?$  You have a geometric distribution in the number of tries.  For $n=2$ you have two states:  $A$ says you have not succeeded the last time and $B$ says you succeeded the last time.  Let $a$ be the expected number of tries  from state $A$ and $b$ be the expected number of tries from state $B$.  Then write two equations:  If you are in state $a$ you have $a=0.98(1+b)+0.02(1+a)$ because you have $0.98$ chance to succeed and go to state $B$ with one more try and $0.02$ chance to go to state $A$ with one more try.  You should be able to write a similar equation for $b$ and solve them.

for more general $n$, you start with no successes.  You can fail the first try, or succeed the first and fail the second, or ... succeed $n-1$ times and fail the $n^{\text{th}}$ try, or succeed $n$ times.  The first terms all take you back to start.

Comment: is there any tutorial on that Kind of statistic approach ?

Comment: @user1769184:  I don't know.